# Solving the recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm interested in learning how can we solve this linear non-homogeneous recurrence relation?

$$a_z = 2a_{n-1} - 1a{n-2} + (s^2 + 1)$$

Comment: [This user - jtm22](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/60244/jtm22) just deleted an identical question after my comment on *another* of his (now-deleted) questions that this is from a local take-home exam

Answer (score 12):

$a_n=2^n\left(\frac{1}{12}n^4+\frac{1}{3}n^3+\frac{11}{12}n^2+\left(p-\frac{4}{3}\right)n+q\right)$, where $p, q$ are arbitrary constants.

If $a_0$ and $a_1$ are known, then take $p=a_0-\frac{1}{2}a_1+\frac{8}{3}, \; q=a_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite it as:
$$
a_{n + 2} = 4 a_{n + 1} - 4 a_n + (n^2 + 4 n + 5) 2^{n + 2}
$$
Define the generating function $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$. Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, noting that:
$$
z \frac{d}{dz} \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n = \sum_{n \ge 0} n c_n z^n
$$
This gives:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1}{z^2} = 4 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} - 4 A(z)
   + \left( 
       z \frac{d}{dz} \left(z \frac{d}{dz} \right)
          + 4 z \frac{d}{dz}
          + 5
    \right) \frac{4}{1 - 2 z}
$$
Compute the derivatives, work out the value of $A(z)$, split into partial fractions and expand. That gives $a_n$ explicitly. More details in Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). A computer algebra system at hand is nice.

Comment: last piece is not formatted correctly!

Comment: @JennaMagic, premature post :-( Thanks!

Comment: I've never used generating functions before..anyway you can show it all worked out ? =(

Comment: @JennaMagic Take the recurrence, multiply by $z^n$ and sum for $n \ge 0$. You can identify the resulting sums as the fractions I show, the terms from the forcing function come from the note. The result is a linear equation in $A(z)$, which gives a fraction. Split into partial fractions, and you are set.

Comment: @JennaMagic, question was closed so I can't add another answer. But you can work it out youself, and check if it satisfies your recurrence. Take a look at the book I link to (the 2nd edition is available free there).

Answer (score 3):

Define the operator $T$ on sequences by $(T(x_n))_n = x_n- 2x_{n-1}$.

If $x_n$ is of the form $P(n)2^n$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then $T(x_n)_n = (P(n)-P(n-1))2^n = Q(n)2^n$ where $Q(n) = P(n)-P(n-1)$ is of degree $k-1$.
Also, $\ker T$ is obviously the set of sequences of the form $a2^n$, so $T^{-1}(Q(n)2^n) = \{P(n)2^n / P(n)-P(n-1) = Q(n)\}$

You have $T(T(a_n))_n = b_n = (n^2+1)2^n$, and so $a_n \in T^{-1}(T^{-1}(b_n)$
First you have to find a polynomial $P_1$ such that $P_1(n)-P_1(n-1) = n^2+1$, which gives you $T^{-1}(b_n)$ up to $2^n$, then find a polynomial $P_2$ such that $P_2(n)-P_2(n-1) = P_1(n)$, which gives you the solutions up to $2^n$ and $n2^n$

Comment: Anyway to show it worked out?

Comment: It says "kerT" on the 4th line?

Comment: and what would those 2 polynomials be?

Answer (score 3):

If we do the standard thing and look for a solution of the homogeneous equation (ignoring the ($n^2+1)2^n$ part for the moment) of the form $a_n=r^n$ we find that $(r-2)^2=0$, so that $r=2$ is a double solution.

In this case the general solution for the homogeneous equation in $a_n$ becomes $a_n=(An+B)2^n$

Note that this is of the form $p(n)2^n$ which has also appeared on the right hand side, and we want a particular solution of the form $p(n)2^n$.

If we try $p(n)=cn+d$ we find that we always get zero. If $p(n)$ is quadratic, we get $E2^n$ where $E$ is constant. Because our homogeneous solution takes up two degrees (0 and 1) which we'd normally try, we have to add two to the degree to get a quadratic in $n$ on the RHS, so our particular solution uses a quartic of the form $wn^4+xn^3+yn^2$ (lower degrees just go to zero). $w, x,y$ are chosen to give $n^2+1$.

This approach can be proved in various ways, including generating functions.

Comment: but this doesn't show the answer?

Comment: @JennaMagic You didn't ask for a solution for the recurrence, but said you were interested in learning how we can solve problems like it. I have given a method, and some clues as to why it works the way it does.

Comment: A solution will be of the form $a_n=(wn^4+xn^3+yn^2+An+B)2^n$. You will be able to compute $w,x,y$ - the particular part of the solution - by plugging this form into the recurrence. To find $A$ and $B$ you need something like the values $a_0$ and $a_1$ (any two values will do, since there are two numbers to find).

Comment: Mark, please see [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383570/solving-the-recurrence-relation-a-n-4a-n-1-4a-n-2-n2-12n/383609?noredirect=1#comment821173_383609) and the following. Regards,

Comment: @The Chaz: I have noted the comments on Ron Gordon's answer, which is very similar to mine. I was not anyway inclined to do all the work, because doing the calculations will help to see what is going on.

Comment: You are definitely a teacher at heart. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Split the solution $a_n$ in a homogeneous piece $h_n$ and a particular piece $p_n$ such that $a_n = h_n + p_n$.  The homogeneous solution solves

$$a_n - 4 a_{n-1} + 4 a_{n-2} = 0 \implies a_n = A\, 2^n + B \, n\, 2^n$$

The particular solution should not overlap with the homogeneous solution.  Trial and error reveals that a solution of the form $C \, n^2 \, 2^n$ is not sufficient to produce the RHS.  Rather, a term $n^4 \, 2^n$ is necessary to produce the $n^2 \, 2^n$ piece on the RHS.  That said, lower-order terms are needed to produce the rest of the RHS.  Thus

$$p_n = C\,n^4 \, 2^n + D \, n^3\, 2^n + E\, n^2 \, 2^n$$

Plug this into the recurrence and determine the values of $C$, $D$, and $E$

You then need initial conditions to get $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Can we show this solved?

Comment: Ron, please don't (at least for now). This is part of a take-home test at my local university.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: I had no idea.  I guess this is May and I should be wary of these.

Comment: @JennaMagic: I will post the solution in a week.

Comment: There is no way anyone could have known. I just so happened to have seen this question on the final.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: this is an ongoing matter of discussion at M.SE.  Should we be known as the site everyone goes to for cheating.  I guess I should be wary of those who demand the answers.

Comment: Please note: I have singled you out, as so far yours is the only answer within the scope of the course (i.e. solve the homogeneous equation, etc.)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: no problem, I really don't mind.  In fact, glad you spoke up.

Comment: Wasn't on my take home but this is for an extra credit opportunity.  I apologize!

Comment: @Jenna: no prob, but I think this is the best course of action for the time being while it is an exam question for someone else.  We just don't want the site to be a haven for cheaters.  That said, try to do out the algebra and solve for $C$, $D$, and $E$.